# Axios Response in Vue3 is undefined but only for the first POST request. Then its working fine

Tags: axios, vuejs3, eventemitter

I have two Vue 3 components:

In the first one I have this function that is triggered by pressing a button and emmits the response from the backend to the second component:

```
methods: {
        postMessage(){
             
            label = {'label': this.selectedOption, 'status': 'true'}

            const path = 'http://localhost:5000/labeling';
            axios.post(path, label)
            .then(response => 
            {   
                console.log('response right after arriving',response)
                this.submit_status = response.data
                console.log('submit_status right after arriving_2',this.submit_status)
                this.status = response.data.status
                console.log('response right after arriving_3',this.status)
            })
            //.catch(error => console.error('error:',error));
            console.log('exit the response function?')
            if(status == 'False')
            {
                alert('entire csv file labeled')
            }
            else{
                this.emitter.emit('received_coordinates',this.submit_status);
            }
        }
```

In the second component the emitted variable 'received_data' is used.

```
mounted(){
        this.index = 1
        this.emitter.on("received_coordinates", (received_data) => {
                    this.coordinates = received_data.scan_cart
                    this.index = received_data.index
                }
        })
    },
```

Following error occurs **ONLY** after the first emitting process:

received_data.scan_data is undefined (triggered by the second component)

I have already checked the network tab in my browser and the data is transmitted correctly. It seems like the error occurs before the .then statement is triggered:

[image]

After that the response data arrives but the error already occured:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to put the emit inside the `.then()`:

```
methods: {
        postMessage(){
             
            label = {'label': this.selectedOption, 'status': 'true'}

            const path = 'http://localhost:5000/labeling';
            axios.post(path, label)
            .then(response => 
            {   
                this.submit_status = response.data
                this.status = response.data.status
            
                // emit event after this.submit_status has been set
                if(status == 'False')
                {
                    alert('entire csv file labeled')
                }
                else{
                    this.emitter.emit('received_coordinates',this.submit_status);
                }
            })
        }
```

Currently, the event is emitted right after the post request was sent, so before `this.submit_status` is set, giving you an error when accessing a property on undefined.